# removing \r \n and escape characters from html

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace, imap

I have the following html, which I have extracted from an email using imap_fetchbody,

```
<div dir=\"ltr\"><br><div class=\"gmail_quote\"><div dir=\"ltr\"><br><div class=\"gmail_quote\"><div class=\"\">
---------- Forwarded message ----------<br>
<span style=\"font-family:&quot;Helvetica&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;\"><\/span>
From: <span style=\"font-family:&quot;Helvetica&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;\">&quot;
<span>xyz<\/span>&quot; &lt;<a href=\"mailto:support@xyz.com\" target=\"_blank\">support@<span>xyz<\/span>.com<\/a>&gt;<\/span><br>
\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nDate: Fri, Apr 18, 2014 at 7:17 PM<br>
Subject: Bla bla xyz<br><\/div><div><div class=\"h5\">To: XYZ &lt;<a href=\"mailto:xyz@gmail.com\" target=\"_blank\">xyz@gmail.com<\/a>&gt;<br><br><br>\r\n\r\n<div dir=\"ltr\">\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n
<div class=\"gmail_quote\"><div><div><div dir=\"ltr\"><div class=\"gmail_quote\"><div dir=\"ltr\"><div><div class=\"gmail_quote\">
<div dir=\"ltr\"><div><div><div class=\"gmail_quote\"><div style=\"word-wrap:break-word\" lang=\"EN-US\">\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n
<div>
<div>
<div>
<blockquote style=\"margin-top:5pt;margin-bottom:5pt\">
<div><div>
<table style=\"width:100%;background:none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(207,207,207)\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\" width=\"100%\">
<tbody>
<tr>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n
<td style=\"width:325pt;padding:0in\" width=\"650\">\r\n\r\n<div align=\"center\"><table style=\"width:325pt;background:none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(207,207,207)\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\" width=\"650\">\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n
<tbody><tr>
<td style=\"padding:0in 0in 5.25pt\"><p style=\"text-align:center\" align=\"center\">
<span style=\"font-size:7.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;;color:rgb(64,64,64)\">If you are unable to see this message, 
<a href=\"http:\/\/click.e.xyz.com\/?qs=3771d7c90c958f02a4b2e78494f12a3116ddb15df79b8d04cdf5aeba42012b118\" target=\"_blank\">
<span style=\"color:rgb(64,64,64)\">click here<\/span><\/a> to view.<br>
\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nTo ensure delivery to your inbox, please add <a href=\"mailto:support@xyz.com\" target=\"_blank\">support@xyz.com<\/a> to your address book. <\/span><\/p>
<\/td>
<\/tr>
<\/tbody>
<\/table>
<\/div><\/div><\/div><\/div>
```

I want to get rid of all the `\`,`\r`, `\n` and still keep `<` and `>` of the html as is. 
I have tried stripslashes, stripcslashes, nl2br, htmlspecialchars_decode. But I am not able to achieve what I want.
Here is what I have tried along with `imap_qprint` function,

```
$text = stripslashes(imap_qprint($text));
$body = preg_replace('/(\v|\s)+/', ' ', $text );
```

Res: It doesn't remove all the white space characters.

Answer (score 2):

Match the following regex:

`(\\r|\\n|\\)` with the `g` modifier

and replace with

`''` (empty string)

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/mS3wM2

Comment: `$message = preg_replace('/(\\r|\\n|\\)/g', '', $message );` this should work right ? Its in php. It is throwing warning, `PHP Warning:  preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'g'` I will have to refer some doc now.

Comment: @Rao, Yes. Without the `g` modifier I believe (php doesn't have `g`). Test it to be sure and let me know how it goes.

Comment: @Rao, As Martijn pointed out, php has the `preg_replace_all()` function which is what you want to use.

Comment: This will remove all slashes, even the ones you might want to keep. I'll admit, it does the trick, but this is a canon vs a musquito :) (to be clear, this is not about the regex. Though IMO it's not the best solution, it will work, so no comment about that :) )

Comment: @Martijn, The OP said they "want to get rid of all the \,\r, \n".

Comment: I agree, but when you read the code, you can easily tell it's the escaping slashes, not actually all the slashes. Might've been a poor those of words. (If TS corrects me in this, I'll remove the downvote without hassle)

Comment: @Martijn there is no such function called `preg_replace_all()`

Comment: I would have accepted your answer but I quite couldn't implement it in php.

Answer (score 1):

```
$html = preg_replace('/[\\\\\r\n]/', '', $html);

Match a single character present in the list below «[\\\r\n]»
   A \ character «\\»
   A carriage return character «\r»
   A line feed character «\n»
```

**UPDATE:**

Based on your comment I've updated my answer:

```
$html = preg_replace('%\\\\/%sm', '/', $html);
$html = preg_replace('/\\\\"/sm', '"', $html);
$html = preg_replace('/[\r\n]/sm', '', $html);
```

Comment: @Rao, if my question helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer, tks!

Comment: +1 but can't accept your answer because its better to remove only escaping backslashes rather than removing all backlashes from the text. (as mentioned by Martijn in his answer)

Answer (score 0):

If string functions can do the trick, **always favor stringfunctions above regex´s**. Performace/speed will be better compared to regex's, and they's easier to read in the code:

```
$message = str_replace("\r\n", '', $message ); // replace all newlines, use double quotes!
$message = stripslashes( $message );
```

First you have to remove the newlines. As far as I can tell, the `\r` and `\n` always come together, so I replace them in 1 go. After that, the stripslashes will remove all escaping slashes.
*You have to the the stripslashes after the newlines, else `\r\n` would result in `rn`, making them harder to find*

---

**This works perfect in my tests:**

```
echo '<textarea style="width:100%; height: 33%;">'.$message.'</textarea>';
echo '<hr />';

$message = str_replace("\r\n", '', $message); // use double quotes!
echo '<textarea style="width:100%; height: 33%;">'.$message.'</textarea>';
echo '<hr />';

$message = stripslashes($message);
echo '<textarea style="width:100%; height: 33%;">'.$message.'</textarea>';
```

Comment: Tried this, strings like `\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n` still remain in the output, and also all the `\` are still there, `<\/div>` I want to remove those as well.

Comment: stripslashes is supposed to remove all escaping slashes like <\/div> right? Not sure why, but it ain't removing them.

Comment: Then something is up in your code. I took your html and put into `$message`, and the 3 textarea's do exactly as expected.

Comment: Does php put those slashes back when I put the result in an array?

Comment: Nope. If you want the slashes back, `addslashes()`

Comment: This works and my code was also working all along! I was returning the result from an API which was adding those slashes back. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. Please mark an answer as solution for the next person who encounters this script (And +1 me if you think that worth it ;) )

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this to interpret the escape sequences:

```
function interpret_escapes($str) {
    return preg_replace_callback('/\\\\(.)/u', function($matches) {
        $map = ['n' => "\n", 'r' => "\r", 't' => "\t", 'v' => "\v", 'e' => "\e", 'f' => "\f"];
        return isset($map[$matches[1]]) ? $map[$matches[1]] : $matches[1];
    }, $str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can open the file in vi, it would be as easy as:

`%s/\\r\|\\n//g`

on vi cmd mode